# copying a new file each way and reporting a message to the screen

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The main idea is to copy new files from server to client and copy logs from the client to the server only if the files are 
1. older than the client version
2. if the client does not have the file
Notify the user with write out to text box advising  of new update and restart required

I am trying to copy a config update another issue is folder structure 
would i need to have the complete folder structure in the script all this will be completed without user interaction so silently

I have adapted the code below

display message to only to say if restart required

server layout roughly server>config files
-update
-config
-other config folder
-another config folder

client layout client>program>logs
-log1
-log2

```
Ssource =  "\\server\Tmp\Test.cfg"
$destination = "\\anyclient\Tmp\Destination\"

$TestPath = Test-Path $destination
IF (!$TestPath)
{Copy-Item $source $destination -Verbose write-host "restart required"
PC1 - no file found. Copying}
ELSE
{
IF (((Get-ChildItem $source).Length -ne (Get-ChildItem
$destination).Length) -or ((Get-ChildItem $source).LastWriteTime -ne (Get-    ChildItem $destination).LastWriteTime))
{Copy-Item $source $destination -Force -Verbose}
 write-host = "restart required"
ELSE
{"PC2 - exact file found, nothing copied"}
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated my only problem is this must be powershell v2 compatible

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure wheter you use sharepoint and that stuff but normally there are webservices provided which can be used for up and downloading files like:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true 
$credentials =$webclient.Credentials
```

(just to initialize the webclient) and here is up and download function:

```
$webclient.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

and as a report box I am using a Message Box Method a friend told me about:

```
function Show-MessageBox {
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Message,
    [Validateset('Error', 'Warning', 'Information')]
    [string]$Type
)

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message, $Type, `
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::$Type) 
}
```

this method above can be called like this:

```
Show-MessageBox -Type Information -Message "Error or info code"
```

Type (information means a little icon which will be displayed on the message box and it looks like a blue circle with a white 'i' in it) :D